# Boto3 and OVH: GetObject error the specified bucket is not valid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, ovh

I'm currently trying to implement a get Object request from  Object Storage – S3 API OVH. I have the same implementation for a project using python and wanted to integrate it here, but do to a lack of knowledge of the language I believe I may be missing something.
I'm getting this error:

> The specified bucket is not valid.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL,
    region_name=REGION_NAME
)

s3_response_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCK_NAME_IS_STRING, Key='KEY_STRING')

print(s3_response_object)
```

Things I've tried:

I confirmed that the bucket name is accurate and verified the relevant permissions. These environment variables have been successfully utilized in another project using JavaScript without issues.

Notably, altering variables such as aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key did not affect the error message, suggesting that the issue might be related to a format error.

ovh relevant documentation:

> Object Storage - Endpoints and Object Storage geoavailability

https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-ie-public-cloud-storage-s3-location?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0047393

> Object Storage Swift - S3/Swift REST API compatibility

https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/en-ie-public-cloud-storage-pcs-s3-swift-rest-api-compatibility?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0047197

Comment: What is `BUCK_NAME_IS_STRING`? Just from the name of the variable, it looks like you're passing a bool/control varaible here, not the actual bucket name

Comment: Where is `s3_client` defined?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same AWS Region as the location of the Bucket? Why are you passing a `ENDPOINT_URL` -- are you using Amazon S3, or another service? If it is S3, there would typically be no need to pass this value.

Comment: **Side-note:** Rather than passing credentials via variables, the recommended method is to run `aws configure` (part of the AWS CLI) and store that information in a configuration file. You can then simply use `client = boto3.client('s3')`

Comment: @KingOtto I am passing the actual bucket name but for reference, I have chosen BUCK_NAME_IS_STRING.

Comment: @AnonCoward I'm passing the credentials as parameters for now: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm using another service called ovh cloud  that's why I need to pass the endpoint_url otherwise it won't recognize it. https://www.ovhcloud.com/en/public-cloud/object-storage/

As per the was I also tried with it, but had the same result so for troubleshooting purposes I'm trying first as a parameter to be able to identify the issue.

Comment: Have you loaded the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to use against ovh? If so, you can test if the credentials are working for that bucket by using `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`

Comment: I still don't see where `s3_client` is defined, only `client`.  This code can't work.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name results in:

An error occurred (InvalidBucketName) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket is not valid.

```aws --version```
aws-cli/1.31.12 Python/3.12.0 Linux/6.6.4-200.fc39.x86_64 botocore/1.33.12

cat ~/.aws/config

[plugins]
endpoint = awscli_plugin_endpoint

[profile default]
region = gra
s3 =
  endpoint_url = https://storage.gra.cloud.ovh.net/v1
  signature_version = s3v4
s3api =
  endpoint_url = https://storage.gra.cloud.ovh.net/v1

Comment: @AnonCoward isn't it this the definition of the client:

```client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL,
    region_name=REGION_NAME
)```
If not could you clarify?

Comment: Well, both the CLI and boto3 say that the named bucket doesn't exist. It isn't complaining about credentials, so it is definitely talking to an S3-like endpoint. It would appear that a bucket with that name does not exist.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Using: ```aws s3 ls```  will get me: 

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.gra.amazonaws.com/"

However through my  ~/.aws/credentials I'm passing another endpoint, do you know why is not using this endpoint? 


[profile default]
s3 =
  endpoint_url = <url_endpoint>

Comment: Looks related: [Specific endpoint (S3 OVH) make the boto3 client use the wrong endpoint_url · Issue #3258 · boto/boto3 · GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3258)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did read that post but it only make sense now, thanks this made the day.

Answer (score 0):

### Additional information

Thank you, John, for sharing this post. The link you shared provided the final piece of the puzzle. Here is the bug posted by  *mh4ckt3mh4ckt1c4s*  at

https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3258

I wanted to add some information that is relevant to the issue mentioned on GitHub, which is related to the retrieval of credentials from the OVH control panel. OVH provides a URL in this format: https://storage.***region***.cloud.ovh.net In my case, I was using the wrong URL, as "storage" is the legacy name that is still used for backward compatibility. The correct URL is: https://s3.***region***.cloud.ovh.net**

The problem with the CLI not working was also due to the same reason. However, it was an easy fix - I just had to set it up at `~/.aws/config`

### Solution

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_endpoint_url= https://s3.<region>.cloud.ovh.net,
    region_name=REGION_NAME
)
```